# C# update SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I've tried to write an `update` statement that will update some information in my SQL Server table

Here is my code so far, I can't see the issue.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FirstNameEdit.Text = Session["FirstName"].ToString();
    LastNameEdit.Text = Session["LastName"].ToString();
}

protected void SubmitEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FirstNameEdit.Text == "")
    {
        StatusMessage.Text = "Indtast venligst dit fornavn. ";
    }
    else
    {
        if (LastNameEdit.Text == "")
        {
            StatusMessage.Text = "Indtast venligst dit efternavn. ";
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Break;Integrated Security=True");
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users", connection);
                command.Connection.Open();

                string querystr = "UPDATE Users SET User_FirstName='@User_FirstName', User_LastName='@User_LastName' WHERE User_ID='@User_ID'";
                SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(querystr, connection);

                string User_ID = Session["ID"].ToString();
                string User_FirstName = FirstNameEdit.Text;
                string User_LastName = LastNameEdit.Text;

                query.Parameters.Add("@User_ID", User_ID);
                query.Parameters.Add("@User_FirstName", User_FirstName);
                query.Parameters.Add("@User_LastName", User_LastName);
                query.ExecuteNonQuery();

                string FirstName = FirstNameEdit.Text;
                Session.Add("FirstName", FirstName);
                string LastName = LastNameEdit.Text;
                Session.Add("LastName", LastName);

                StatusMessage.Text = "Din profil er opdateret";

                command.Connection.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                StatusMessage.Text = "Noget er galt, prøv lidt senere";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have also searched a lot, but it's exactly the same I find. Maybe it's something about the SQL query.

Comment: What errors do you get? Also you shouldn't need the `'` wrapping your parameters it should just be `User_FirstName=@User_FirstName`

Comment: So, What do you want from us ?????????

Comment: Haha, as I said, I think there is something wrong with the sql query, but it's fixed now! Well, there is one more thing, it dosen't update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the issue exactly?

I think when specifying the parameter using parameterized query, you don't need to use quote anymore, hence

```
string querystr = "UPDATE Users SET User_FirstName='@User_FirstName', User_LastName='@User_LastName' WHERE User_ID='@User_ID'";
```

should become

```
string querystr = "UPDATE Users SET User_FirstName=@User_FirstName, User_LastName=@User_LastName WHERE User_ID=@User_ID";
```

Comment: What is the User_ID column data type? Perhaps as @Steve said, you may need to convert to int if it is a numeric field.

Comment: If that's so, can you try replacing `string User_ID = Session["ID"].ToString();` to `int User_ID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"].ToString());` ?

Answer (score 4):

Don't enclose the parameters placeholders with single quotes. In that way they becomes simply string literals and your query can't work

```
 string querystr = "UPDATE Users SET User_FirstName=@User_FirstName, " + 
                   "User_LastName=@User_LastName WHERE User_ID=@User_ID";
```

Another thing to consider. Are you sure that your User_ID field is a string (text, nvarchar, varchar) field in the database?. If it is a numeric field then you need to convert the value passed as parameter for that field to a numeric value (I.E. Use Convert.ToInt32)

So, if this is true, the code could be changed as

```
string User_ID = Session["ID"].ToString();
string User_FirstName = FirstNameEdit.Text;
string User_LastName = LastNameEdit.Text;

query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_ID", Convert.ToInt32(User_ID));
query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_FirstName", User_FirstName);
query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_LastName", User_LastName);
query.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I have used the AddWithValue following the recommendation in MSDN that says

> AddWithValue replaces the SqlParameterCollection.Add method that takes
>   a String and an Object. The overload of Add that takes a string and an
>   object was deprecated because of possible ambiguity with the
>   SqlParameterCollection.Add overload that takes a String and a
>   SqlDbType enumeration value where passing an integer with the string
>   could be interpreted as being either the parameter value or the
>   corresponding SqlDbType value. Use AddWithValue whenever you want to
>   add a parameter by specifying its name and value.

However, the advantage in the implicit conversion it's also the disadvantage since the conversion may not be optimal. I can give as reference this [very thorough article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx)

Another note to keep in mind. Do not swallow exceptions. In your code, the generic message that advise the user of a failure is not enough to let you understand what's going  wrong. You should replace your code with

```
try
{
   ......
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
      // I let you translate... :-)
      StatusMessage.Text = "Noget er galt, prøv lidt senere "  + 
                           "Error message=" + ex.Message;
}
```

Comment: my table structure is User_ID   User_Username   User_Password    User_FirstName    User_LastName

Comment: User_ID has INT as datatype

Comment: Then it is better to use the appropriate conversion. I will show an example in my answer above

Comment: Cool, I've just started coding c# so it's good to know, thank you. But unfortunately  it didn't work :(

Comment: Did you get any error message? Did the Session["ID"] really contains a number?

Comment: I have just checked your code above. Please remove the generic catch and add a more precise handler because in that way you don't know what exactly doesn't work. Updating answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as other people said - don't use single quota in the query, you don't need that.

Secondly: when you are defining *Parameters* to your command, you may use two variants:

1) `query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_FirstName", User_FirstName);`

or

2) `query.Parameters.Add("@User_FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = User_FirstName;`

You can't use `query.Parameters.Add("@User_FirstName", User_FirstName);`

Answer (score -1):

```
string queryStr = "UPDATE SET USER (account, user, password, permission_level)" +
"VALUES ('" + tbxAccount.Text + "', '" + tbxUsername.Text +
"', '" + tbxPassword.Text + "', '" + tbxPermission.Text + "');";
```